# SQL Left Fuzzy Join with Levenshtein Distance

Tags: sql, left-join, ssms, levenshtein-distance, fuzzyjoin

I have two data sets from two different systems being merged together within SQL, however, there is a slight difference within the naming conventions on the two systems. The change in convention is not consistent across the larger data sample but normally requires one modification to match.

| System 1 data | System 2 data |
| --- | --- |
| AA0330 | AA_330 |
| AA0340 | AA_340 |
| AA0331 | AA_331 |
| AA0341 | AA-341 |

I have been using the below Levenshtein distance SQL function too fuzzy match and get the below result, however, end up with duplicate joins. How could I modify my code to mitigate this?

```
SELECT [System1].[mvmt1],
       [System2].[mvmt2]       
FROM [System1]
left join [System2] 
     ON dbo.ufn_levenshtein([System1].[mvmt1], [System2].[mvmt2]) < 2;
```

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=552&m=0

Current output:

| System 1 data | System 2 data |
| --- | --- |
| AA0330 | AA_330 |
| AA0330 | AA_340 |
| AA0340 | AA_340 |
| AA0331 | AA_331 |
| AA0341 | AA-341 |

How can I make sure I only get one outcome from the join?

Comment: then look at the function , include function in the select to see what it returns

Comment: The function just returns the levenshtein relationship as an int. I am then using this within my left join. How would I make the left join only return the first match similar to a vlookup?

Comment: even if with left join you are matching table a and b based on the result of the func , so Levenshtein Distance between AA0330 from table a is less that 2 from (AA_330, AA_340) in table b and that's why you have 2 results there

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway that I could clean the table within the same query to only give back one result? Almost a group by system 1??

Comment: Levenshtein is not really the right tool for the job, as you've discovered. I also cannot imagine it is very performant. A better bet would be to use, say (based on your sample), the first 2 and last 3 characters. Or you can use nested replaces until one side fits the format of the other.

Comment: Why don't you just strip out hyphens and underscores?

Comment: @shawnt00 It could be an additional character such as 0 or 1. The error is not consistent. For example 7A0330 to 7A330

Answer (score 0):

not the best solution , but you can compare first 2 character and last 3 character , if all the codes are following the same pattern (2 character on right and 3 digit at the end ):

```
SELECT [System1].[mvmt1],
       [System2].[mvmt2]       
FROM [System1]
inner join [System2] 
     ON left(mvmt1,2) = left(mvmt2,2) 
     and right(mvmt1,3) = right(mvmt2,3)
```

Answer (score -1):

what about something like this (sorry about the poor formatting):

```
WITH Initial_Fuzzy_Join as(
SELECT [System1].[mvmt1],
       [System2].[mvmt2]       ,
dbo.ufn_levenshtein([System1].[mvmt1], [System2].[mvmt2]) as StringDistanceMetric
FROM [System1]
left outer join [System2] 
     ON dbo.ufn_levenshtein([System1].[mvmt1], [System2].[mvmt2]) < 2
)
SELECT mvmt1, mvmt2, max(StringDistanceMetric)
FROM Initial_Fuzzy_Join
Group by mvmt1,mvmt2
```

Comment: Could you use a better formatting and explain what the sql does?